# download multiple files from sourceforge

Tags: wget, curl, download

Is there any way to download / mirror a folder structure with **many** files from sourceforge using wget/curl/similar tool?

I've seen some examples using rsync or scp but I think that works only for SF project owners (cause it needs login, password and filesystem path).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it with *wget*.

If you are using HTTP

```
wget --no-check-certificate -e robots=off --user=user --password='pswd' -r URL
```

If you use FTP :

```
wget -r ftp://username:password@ftp.your_domain.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [`httrack`](http://www.httrack.com/) for downloading/mirroring web content from a site.

```
$ httrack http://2011.example.com -K -w -O . -%v --robots=0 -c1 %e0
```

After it runs you're left with a directory structure that's local and browseable. For example:

```
$ ls -l
total 304
-rw-r--r--  1 saml saml   4243 Aug 17 10:20 backblue.gif
-rw-r--r--  1 saml saml    828 Aug 17 10:20 fade.gif
drwx------  3 saml saml   4096 Aug 17 10:20 hts-cache
-rw-rw-r--  1 saml saml    233 Aug 17 10:20 hts-in_progress.lock
-rw-rw-r--  1 saml saml   1517 Aug 17 10:20 hts-log.txt
-rw-------  1 saml saml 271920 Aug 17 10:22 hts-nohup.out
-rw-r--r--  1 saml saml   5141 Aug 17 10:20 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 10 saml saml   4096 Aug 17 10:21 2011.example.com
```

As it downloads you'll see the following type of output:

```
Bytes saved:    21,89KiB           Links scanned:   12/45 (+4)
Time:   2s                         Files written:   4
Transfer rate:  2,65KiB/s (2,65KiB/s)  Files updated:   1
Active connections:     1          Errors:  7

Current job: parsing HTML file (57%)
 request -  2011.example.com/cgi-bin/hostnames.pl   0B /    8,00KiB
```

It can be backgrounded and/or aborted and later resumed. This is just the tip of the iceberg in terms of it's features. There is also a GUI for both setting up a download and monitoring it as it progresses.

There is extensive documentation on the [`httrack` website](http://www.httrack.com/html/fcguide.html) and by googling.